# Form made with SMTP sent. Form sending takes too much time

Tags: php, email, smtp

So I have made a little SMTP php code that sends emails at the completion of the form to a desired account, now the problem is that when the form is going to be sent it takes a lot of time to send. So ive made an exceed time, after the exceed time ended i receive this errors.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SMTPClass.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_HOST in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMTPClass.php
>   on line 39

FORM CODE :

```
<?php

include('SMTPconfig.php');
   include('SMTPClass.php');
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
   {
       $to = $_POST['to'];
       $from = $_POST['from'];
       $subject = $_POST['sub'];
       $body = $_POST['message'];
       $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, 
   $from, $to, $subject, $body);
       $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
   }
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <title>form</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="">
         <table width="500px">
            <tr>
               <td width="20%">To : </td>
               <td ><input type="text" name="to" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>From :</td>
               <td><input type='text' name="from" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Subject :</td>
               <td><input type='text' name="sub" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Message :</td>
               <td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td><input type="submit" value=" Send " /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

SMTP CLASSES :

```
<?php


class SMTPClient
{

  function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, 
  $to, $subject, $body)
  {

    $this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
    $this->SmtpUser = base64_encode ($SmtpUser);
    $this->SmtpPass = base64_encode ($SmtpPass);
    $this->from = $from;
    $this->to = $to;


    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->body = $body;


    if ($SmtpPort == "") 
    {
      $this->PortSMTP = 25;
    } else {
      $this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
    }


  }



  function SendMail ()
  {

    if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP)) 
    {

      fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n");  
      $talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 

      fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
      $talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
      fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
      $talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);

      fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
      $talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);

      fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n");  
      $talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );  
      fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n");  
      $talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024); 

      fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
      $talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );


      fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
      $talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);

      //CLOSE CONNECTION AND EXIT ... 

      fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n");  
      fclose($SMTPIN); 
         //  
    }  

    return $talk;
  }        

}


?>
```

SMTP SERVER :

```
<?php
$SmtpServer="smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$SmtpPort="465";
$SmtpUser="username@yahoo.com";
$SmtpPass="yahoopassword";

?>
```